# Silverstripe 3 - Image relation on SiteConfig DataObject

Tags: silverstripe

SS does not save the relation of a DataObject (extension) to an Image; I think the problem might be with the SiteConfig ModelAdmin.

This is (part of) the Site Config extensions class:

```
class CustomSiteConfig extends DataExtension { 
    static $has_many = array(
        'HeaderSections' => 'HeaderSection',
        'FooterSections' => 'FooterSection',
    );

    public function updateCMSFields(FieldList $fields) {
        ...
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Header', $gridFieldHeader);
        ...
    }
}
```

I have added the needed code to _config of course.

This is (part of) the DataObject extension HeaderSection:

```
class HeaderSection extends DataObject {
    public static $has_many = array(
        'Sections' => 'HeaderSubSection'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        ...
        $gridField = new GridField('Sections', 'Dropdown Sections', $this->Sections(), $gridFieldConfig);
        ...
    }
}
```

And the DataObject extension class being belonging to HeaderSection is called HeaderSubSection:

```
class HeaderSubSection extends DataObject {
    static $has_one = array(
        'HeaderSection' => 'HeaderSection',
        'InternalLink' => 'SiteTree',
        'Image' => 'Image'
    );

    public function getCMSFields() {
        ...
        $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', new UploadField('Image', 'Section Image', $this->Image()));
        ...
    }
}
```

Everything else works, all the other fields save (including 'InternalLink' and its relationship), however I cannot get the image to save.

Do I need to move the Header Sections to it's own ModelAdmin page, and then link them back to the SiteConfig somehow?

Comment: shouldn't `HeaderSection` have a $has_one relation back to SiteConfig? Although, not sure it's related.

Comment: @colymba This breaks SS.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding another Image field to has_one, and it worked.

Guess SS doesn't like naming Image fields "Image".